# Can I release a new app with old bundle identifier by deleting old app?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I've developed an application and its old version is live on App Store. Now I'm confused about App Store submission. I have following questions regarding App Store submission of my app.

- There is already an app is released from client's apple account with the bundle identifier like "com.myapp" and he want to release an app with the same bundle identifier, so can I delete the old app and release the new app with the same bundle identifier?

  - If yes, then what will be effect to the user who has an old app in their devices?
  - if no, then is there any work around to use old bundle identifier for new app?

I've read some article saying that app bundle identifier can't be used same for two different application on App Store and If I use the same bundle identifier(used in old app) for my application, then it will be released as an update to an old app, I think?

So do I need to suggest client to go with the new bundle identifier instead of an old one?

Comment: do you want app publish in same developer account or different  account?

Comment: From same account...

Comment: you can't use deleted app bundle identifier ,if you want  fresh app then create new bundle identifier otherwise reuse old bundle and user will notify when new update

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete a bundle identifier and recreate one with the same name, you need to use a new one for a new app.

If you reuse an old identifier and release a new version than the users of the old app will receive an update to the new app. But I don't know if Apple review team will allow this.